# How to set True as default value for BooleanField on Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, checkbox, default

I'm using `BooleanField` in Django.

By default, the checkbox generated by it is unchecked state. I want the state to be checked by default. How do I do that?

Answer (score 230, accepted):

If you're just using a vanilla form (not a ModelForm), you can set a Field initial value ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.initial ) like

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = forms.BooleanField(initial=True)
```

If you're using a ModelForm, you can set a default value on the model field ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#default ), which will apply to the resulting ModelForm, like

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Finally, if you want to dynamically choose at runtime whether or not your field will be selected by default, you can use the initial parameter to the form when you [initialize it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial):

```
form = MyForm(initial={'my_field':True})
```

Comment: Thanks for `form = MyForm(initial={'my_field':True})`, I didn't find it straight away in the documentation.

Comment: This answer is actually _wrong_ : **initial** value **is not default** value as mentioned in @D.W. [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49962098/6709630)

Answer (score 149):

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    any_field = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: Where is this documented? There's mention of `initial` in the docs (for unbound form), but not `default`

Comment: in this answer, the answerer is using a model field, not a form field. That's where the difference is. This tripped me up because I skipped over it just to see the default kwarg. Default isn't a valid forms.Form kwarg. Just wanted to post that to clear this answer up a little, since it has 0 commentary to it.

Comment: This only works for form model fields. Also, changing the model default just to display the initial differently is a bit much, specially when setting the initial value is so simple.

Comment: initial is from older Django. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield

Answer (score 12):

I am using django==1.11. The answer get the most vote is actually wrong. Checking the document from django, it says:

> initial -- A value to use in this Field's initial display. This value
>           is *not* used as a fallback if data isn't given.

And if you dig into the code of form validation process, you will find that, for each fields, form will call it's **widget's** `value_from_datadict` to get actual value, so this is the place where we can inject default value.

To do this for `BooleanField`, we can inherit from `CheckboxInput`, override default `value_from_datadict` and `init` function.

```
class CheckboxInput(forms.CheckboxInput):
    def __init__(self, default=False, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CheckboxInput, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.default = default

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        if name not in data:
            return self.default
        return super(CheckboxInput, self).value_from_datadict(data, files, name)
```

Then use this widget when creating `BooleanField`.

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    bool_field = forms.BooleanField(widget=CheckboxInput(default=True), required=False)
```

Comment: Valid for `Django 3.0` too. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I found the cleanest way of doing it is this.

Tested on Django 3.1.5

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_boolean = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=True)
```

[I found the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5340664/9545326)

Answer (score 3):

In Django 3.0 the default value of a BooleanField in **model.py** is set like this:

```
class model_name(models.Model):
    example_name = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to check the default state in BooleanField is:

```
   active = forms.BooleanField(
    widget=forms.CheckboxInput(
        attrs={
            'checked': True
        }
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `initial` and `default` properties were not working for me, if that's your case try this:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    validated = forms.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['validated'].widget.attrs['checked'] = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change inital of BooleanField:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserConfirmForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['bool_field'].initial = True
```

but it didn't work.

My solve:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['initial'] = {'bool_field': True}
    super(UserConfirmForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

It works like:

```
UserConfirmForm(initial={'bool_field':True})
```

but we can't call form in Generic editing views.
I think this is a great alternative to a regular call form object.

Answer (score 0):

If `default=True` in [models.BooleanField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield) below doesn't work in `models.py`:

```py
# "models.py"

class MyModel(models.Model):   # Here
    state = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Then, use the following solutions below in `admin.py`:

```py
# "admin.py"

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['initial'] = {'state': True}
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
```

Or:

```py
# "admin.py"

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['state'].widget.attrs['checked'] = True

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
```

Or:

```py
# "admin.py"

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    state = forms.BooleanField(initial=True, required=False)

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
```

Or:

```py
# "admin.py"

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    state = forms.BooleanField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxInput(
            attrs={
                'checked': True
            }
        )
    )

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
```

Or:

```py
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'state': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'checked':True}),
        }

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
```