# pre-selected checkbox in django with django forms

Tags: django

Am trying to display a pre-selected checkbox in `Django` :

```
option =  forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=True)
```

but the `checkbox` shows up un-checked. Am using `django 1.3 beta`. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, only I'm building a dynamic form, adding fields inside my forms __init__.

Comment: Is this a ModelForm? If you are passing in an instance, the instance may be overriding the value for option.

Answer (score 12):

```
import django
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
     option = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=True)

>>>print MyForm()
<tr><th><label for="id_option">Option:</label></th><td><input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="option" id="id_option" /></td></tr>
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 3, 0, 'beta', 1)
>>>
```

As you can see the checked="checked" is properly set.

Are you sure you are not modifying something with onload javascript ?

Comment: No am not modifying anything with javascript. And no option = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=True) , doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

Set the attributes field:

```
  options = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label='some label',  choices=(('happy','Happy'),('sad','Sad')),
      widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'checked' : 'checked'}))
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
option = forms.BooleanField(
            widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'checked': True})
        )
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow! Add some more details to your answer other than code. That would help others better to understand.